# How to collect all "instances" of a static class with genric type in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, static

I'm unit-testing my c# application synchron.
Inside my application i have some static classes and i want to reset them between test cases, without writing/using a new test framework or similar.

While i have decided to hardcode my static resets into TestCleanup, i wonder if i can collect statics automatically during runtime.

As the title says, i have a static class with a generic type, so during runtime i have multiple "instances" of that static class for each diffrent type.

is there any possibility to collect all statics on runtime in general?

if not, is there atleast some way to get all type "versions/instances" of a generic static class,
so i don't have to hardcode every possibly used type?

```
    public static class DialogControlService<DialogType>
    {
        public static DialogResult DesiredDialogResult { get; set; }
        public static dynamic Attribute { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to have a type initializer (`static DialogControlService() {...}`) that registers the type (using the generic type argument) somewhere, in a thread-safe way.

Comment: So a static base class, which holds somehow a list of all used types?

Comment: I wouldn't use a base type as the collector - I'd probably have a side-by-side non-generic `static class DialogControlService`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody finding this here is my classes, which are used to programatically filling forms:

```
 public static class DialogControlService<DialogType>
{
    public static DialogResult DesiredDialogResult { get; set; }
    public static dynamic Attribute { get; set; }

    static DialogControlService()
    {
        DialogControlRegistrationService.Register(typeof(DialogType));
    }
}

public static class DialogControlRegistrationService
{
    public static List<Type> RegisteredTypes { get; private set; }
    public static void Register(dynamic type)
    {
        RegisteredTypes.Add(type);
    }

    static DialogControlRegistrationService()
    {
        RegisteredTypes = new List<Type>();
    }
}
```

and here is the code to reset all statics with generic type:

```
 foreach (Type T in DialogControlRegistrationService.RegisteredTypes)
            {
                Type genericType = typeof(DialogControlService<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { T });
                var property = genericType.GetProperty("DesiredDialogResult",
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                property.SetValue(genericType, DialogResult.None);
                property = genericType.GetProperty("Attribute",
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                property.SetValue(genericType, null);
            }
            DialogControlRegistrationService.RegisteredTypes.Clear();
```